# Let $\,g$ be the function defined on the set of real numbers by.....

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

I was thinking about the following problem which is as follows:

[image]

*My Attempt*: Case 1: Let $c$ be the arbitrary rational number.Let $\{x_n\}$ be the sequence of irrational numbers that converge to $c$. By density property that is $\exists$ an irrational number between any real numbers,assures us that such a sequence does exist. 
Now,since $g(x_n)=0, \forall n \in \Bbb N$,we have $\lim_{n \to \infty} g(x_n)=e^{x_n}=e^c\,\,$ while $g(c)=1.$ Therefore,$g$ is not continuous at $c$. In the same way,we can show by taking  $c$ be the arbitrary irrational number, $g$ is not continuous at $c$.

So, I think option 1 is the correct choice. Am I right?

**My next question**: Can someone explain how to find the number of ideals in the ring $R[x]\over {x^2-1}$ ?

Comment: $g$ is not continuous at $x=0$?

Comment: If the choices are ABCDE, how can you say option 1?

Comment: sorry sir.I meant option A

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your idea is correct - almost! First, your notation is a bit confusing. If $(x_n)$ is a sequence of irrational numbers wich converges to a rational number $c$, then you have
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}g(x_n)=\lim_{n\to\infty}e^{x_n}=e^c.
$$
But $e^c\neq 1=g(c)$, UNLESS...? So your function is not continuous at $c$ UNLESS...? For $c$ being irrational you have indeed discontinuity.

Comment: thanks for pointing out the mistake. Do you have any idea about 2nd question?

Comment: the second question is about algebra, which is not really what I like ;) so I recommend you to open a new question for this.